# Find rows in one table and move it to a second table with NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a SQL Server 2014 database with a table with a lot of data (at full speed it could be millions of rows) named `Positions`. The `Id` is a primary key, and there aren't other keys or foreign relationships on this table.

Suppose I have a list of `n` elements like `[{a1, b1, c1}, ... , {an; bn; cn}]`, I have to make a search inside `Positions` table and get all the rows that match:

```
(columnA == a1 && columnB == b1 && columnC == c1)
OR 
(columnA == an && columnB == bn && columnC == cn)
```

This query could produce from 0 to n rows (i.e. There aren't two rows with same `{a, b c}`) The resulting rows, should be deleted from `Partitions` tables and inserted into a second table named `DeletedPositions` and everything should be done in atomic manner.

I should do this in NHibernate, now since I don't know NHibernate:

1. Do I have some facility for this type of operations?
2. Should I use NHibernate or a batched SQL command will perform better?
3. How Can I ensure that all (or nothing) rows will be moved?

This do the Job, how can I improve it to make related insert?

```
            var configuration = new Configuration().DataBaseIntegration(db =>
            {

                db.ConnectionString = @"Server=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;";
                db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                db.BatchSize = 700;
            });

            var mapper = new ModelMapper();
            mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());

            HbmMapping mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
            configuration.AddMapping(mapping);

            var sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

            IList<PositionDTO> p = null;

            using (IStatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession()) {
                p = statelessSession
                    .QueryOver<PositionDTO>()
                    .Where(Restrictions.On<PositionDTO>(y => y.ColumnA).IsIn(a))
                    .And(Restrictions.On<PositionDTO>(y => y.ColumnB).IsIn(b))
                    .And(Restrictions.On<PositionDTO>(y => y.ColumnC).IsIn(c))
                    .List<PositionDTO>();


                using (ITransaction transaction = statelessSession.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (var t in p)
                    {
                        statelessSession.Delete(t);
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. With NHibernate, use a transaction, with adequate isolation level, spanning  a HQL `insert` query followed by a `delete` query. Preferably those queries should be named for being validated at session factory bootstrap, but if you have to dynamically construct it, then go for a "built in code" HQL string. Basic partial example:

```xml
<!-- put that in your .hbm.xml mappings -->
<query name="yourInsertsQuery">
insert into YourTarget
  (
    prop1, prop2, prop3
  )
  select s.propA, sre.propB, ot.propC
    from YourSource s
    inner join s.SomeRelatedEntities sre
      with sre.anythingOnWhichYouHaveAdditionalRestrictions = :someParam
    left join s.OtherThings ot
    where s.someProp = :someOtherParam
      and o.someBooleanCol = false
</query>
```

```cs
// If you required such a high isolation level, so be it, but try
// avoiding it otherwise.
var tran = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
try
{
    session.GetNamedQuery("yourInsertsQuery")
        .SetParameter("someParam", someValue)
        .SetParameter("someOtherParam", someOtherValue)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
    session.GetNamedQuery("yourDeleteQuery")
        .SetParameter("someParam", someValue)
        .SetParameter("someOtherParam", someOtherValue)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
    tran.Commit()
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        tran.Rollback();
    }
    catch(Exception rollbackEx)
    {
        // better log rollbackEx then swallow it (no throw in this nested catch)
        // to let original trouble bubble up.
    }
    // Let original failure bubble up
    throw;
}
```

2. Edit: in fact there will not have a big performance difference doing it using SQL. I was thinking about using a `merge` with SQL for combining the two operations in one, but this is not doable in your case, since insert target is not the same than delete target.
   You will sill have some difference due to the network latency introduced between the two calls from your app to the DB for handling the operation. This will cause the transaction duration to be a bit longer, potentially blocking other application calls longer. A SQL batch would avoid this additional network latency between the insert and the delete.
   If you go for a sql stored procedure, you can use a named sql query defined in mappings for calling it if you wish: just use the `<sql-query>`, and put your SQL `exec` in it using parameters as in the hql example.
3. Encapsulate your processing in a single transaction.